# Debugging node.js apps in WebStorm 7

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

I am having a strange issue debugging node.js apps in WebStorm 7.

The first time I start the debugger I get the application running:

```
/usr/bin/node --debug-brk=34041 app.js
debugger listening on port 34041
Current Environment: development
Express server listening on port 3000
```

But, after the first time (or if I restart the debugger), I get the debugger running but not the app, like below:

```
/usr/bin/node --debug-brk=42140 app.js
debugger listening on port 42140
```

or

```
/usr/bin/node --debug-brk=51341 app.js
debugger listening on port 51341
```

I need to restart the WebStorm itself in order to debug the app again.
Is it a bug in WebStorm? 
Is it a bug in Node.js? 
Is there a way to make it work properly?

Comment: Odd -- I've had WS7 not hit breakpoints, but the application always starts. Do you have it set to "single instance" in the settings when debugging?

Comment: So, it doesn't work anyway, whether "single instance" is checked or not. I just realized that this behavior also happens outside WebStorm, in my linux terminal. If I run 'node --debug-brk=51341 app.js' it (most of the time) doesn't start the app. If I run 'node --debug=51341 app.js' (without -brk) it runs correctly. Is there a way to configure WebStorm to use --debug instead of --debug-brk?

Comment: Do you have any other logging in your application? Is it possible the app isn't working correctly sometimes? This probably would be best posted to the JetBrains support forums/bug tracker.

Comment: Hi WiredPrairie, no other logging is being used.

Comment: By logging, ... could you add a `console.log("App starting")` at the top of your app.js file to confirm it's not running at all when this problem happens?

Comment: Ah, now I got what you mean. Yes I have some logging when the app starts, like 'Current Environment: development' and 'Express server listening on port 3000'. But it doesn't show up when debugging with -brk

Comment: Ah. That's really strange. Suggest you try here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/home

Comment: Hi Wired, I opened a ticket in the support and the issue was solved in version 7.0.1. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

After contacting the support, I found that it was a bug in the WebStorm, already fixed in version 7.0.1.