# Webstorm debugger for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, webstorm

I'm trying to configure Webstorm for using the node.js' debugger.

I've set the enviroment and everything, the app is running fine with the run button, but with the debugger button it just hangs up writing only:

```
/usr/bin/node --debug-brk=52006 --debug-brk node.js
debugger listening on port 52006
```

and it doesn't work or writes anything on the output.

Any idea of what is missing? I've already installed node-inspector and everything.

EDIT:

After sometime that I run the code, I get:

```
Failed to open socket on port 52708, waiting 1000 ms before retrying
```

Comment: There was an issue that was resolved in 7.0.1 that resolved a similar issue for some people.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging node.js apps in WebStorm 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565310/debugging-node-js-apps-in-webstorm-7)

Comment: it's not that :( updated but I get the same problem. I've updated the description btw!

Comment: Try running your application outside of Webstorm.  I've had troubles before where if the application bombs out quickly, the debugger doesn't connect, and Webstorm doesn't even log things on STDIO.  That shouldn't happen with `--debug-brk`, so it might have been a Node.js bug.

Comment: As I suggested on the other question ... I'd suggest contacting JetBrains and submitting an issue.

Comment: the problem is that it fails in the same way outside webstorm too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with the help of JetBrains. In a few words, I used cluster creating child nodes that weren't connected to the debugger.

Full explanation here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/tickets/13630

Comment: Can you copy the explanation somewhere public?

Comment: "doesn't look like WebStorm problem... Are you using any child processes in your application? What does it look like?

Just FYI- some link you may find useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252310/how-to-fork-a-child-process-that-listens-on-a-different-debug-port-than-the-pare
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1919#comment=27-399951

"