# Debugging a command line NodeJS script in phpStorm 7

Tags: node.js, phpstorm

I have a NodeJS script that is designed for executing on the command line, ala a shell script.

I want to debug my script in phpStorm 7 however the debugger just sits there and doesn't debug my script.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require("fs");

....
```

phpStorm debug console output:

```
/opt/local/bin/node --debug-brk=51096 main.js
debugger listening on port 51096
```

Reading http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html it appears as if the NodeJS plugin is biased towards web applications since most of the instructions contain a line like

```
copy the URL address at which the application is running.
```

Which doesn't make sense in this context.

I can run the script via the NodeJS Run Configuration, but I can't debug.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is this a fault of the plugin?

**UPDATE:**

To answer [lena's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena) questions:

- OS is OSX Snow Leopard
- Java version is 1.6.0_51
- NodeJS version is v0.10.19
- IDE build is phpStorm 7 build 131.374
- NodeJS plugin version 131.488

I had a look at [the link lena mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565310/debugging-node-js-apps-in-webstorm-7) and I do have a similar issue, in that the debugger is started but not the app (see console log output above).  The issue was fixed for that user in WebStorm 7.0.1  Perhaps this issue will be fixed in a point release of phpStorm if the fixes are merged into the codebase.

Finally, I'm aware that the mention of the browser in the phpStorm web help is a red herring, perhaps the documentation should be updated to accommodate the running/debugging of NodeJS scripts that don't have a web component.

Comment: Debugging should work for node.js cmd applications - not using browser doesn't make any difference. What WebStorm build do you use? What is your OS - linux? Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565310/debugging-node-js-apps-in-webstorm-7 - does it look similar?

Comment: I have the same issue when trying to debug my console application. I even got an IDE exception once and PHPStorm told me the JavaScript Debugger crashed.

Comment: @lena Can you comment more on this.  Should I open a ticket on phpStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My PhpStorm7 with Mac(Marverick) also have same problem that node.js debugger don't start app.
and ,restarting debugger cause IDE fatal error as below.

```
com.intellij.javascript.debugger.impl.JSDebugProcess.getBrowserName()Ljava/lang/String;: com.intellij.javascript.debugger.impl.JSDebugProcess.getBrowserName()Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.intellij.javascript.debugger.impl.JSDebugProcess.getBrowserName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.intellij.javascript.debugger.scripts.ScriptManager.getBrowserName(ScriptManager.java:52)
    at com.intellij.javascript.debugger.scripts.RootScriptsNode.buildChildren(RootScriptsNode.java:24)
    at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.CachingSimpleNode.getChildren(CachingSimpleNode.java:36)
    at
```

This fatal error make bug report window pop up,but 'Report to JetBrains' button not enabled,I typed report though,
so I could not report this issue to JetBrains.

I installed PhpStorm7 to debian linux,but same debugger issue occured.

now I have installed Early Access Program PhpStorm 7.1.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

It works!!,break points,step execution etc are no problem.

Comment: i can approve this. i just installed the EAP version and it works!

Comment: PhpStorm 7.1 has just been released!

Comment: It does not crash anymore for me... but the debugger does not work properly... i have a breakpoint on a console.log statement which gets logged but the debugger doesn't suspend the program.

Answer (score 0):

I am also running Mac (Maverick) with PhpStorm7 and have the same issue. When I attempt to debug NodeJS project either it says that the debugger is listening but my application never appears to start or in some cases after several tries I get the error described above ("com.intellij.javascript.debugger.impl.JSDebugProcess.getBrowserName()"). It does not matter weather we are talking a simple command line application or an application written to provide web services, the application simply fails to debug node applications. I will give 7.1 a try. Just thought I would add to the data set out there which seems to indicate this a real software bug and not user error.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped is downgrade to PhpStorm 6.
I now have two versions: 7 is for development and 6 is for debugging node.js

Comment: Upgrade to PhpStorm 7.1